# Rails Completed 401 Unauthorized code with authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, http-status-code-401

In my Rails 4.2 app I am using Devise 3.5.10. Once the admin is logged I am trying to protect with a second password the access to a specific view using authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic only for the admin users.

Here is the controller:

```
class ScreensController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

   layout 'chat'

   def chat
     if current_user.admin?
       if params["full_chat"] == "true"
         authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') do |username, password|
           username == "admin" && password == "your_password"
         end
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

So in an ActiveAdmin view I have this link_to:

```
link_to(I18n.t('admin.full_conversation'), root_url+'chat?full_chat=true#/conversations/'+conversation.id.to_s)
```

And here is the route:

```
get  '/chat' , to: 'screens#chat'
```

it works as expected locally, displaying a modal window asking for the user and password before giving acces to the view if they are right, but once it is deployed to the server I get a 401 code in the loggs:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

And the server gets stuck in a loop.
Any idea about why the behaviour is different locally than in the server will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To start off you can clean up your view by using the proper path which will be something like `screens_chat_path` with params fullscreen and conversations.

`get ':chat', to: 'screens#chat', as: 'chat'`

View

```
link_to(I18n.t('admin.full_conversation'), screen_chat_path(full_chat: true, path: /conversations/'+conversation.id.to_s))
```

Next it seems that there is an issue in this logic:

```
md5_password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password)
       username == "admin" && md5_password == 
User.where(role:2).first.randword
```

How do you figure out the password when it is random here? It seems to be coming back 401 because the Digest you're creating and the random word are not equal.

You can build a master key and hold it as a environment variable and say `ENV['MASTER_KEY'] == password` the logic is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! randword is a propperty of the user object, saved in the database. I know that the name could be confusing but it is not random. And as I already said the code works locally, do you think that this could be the reason that makes it fail in the server?

Comment: Can you better explain to me the md5_password and randword logic? Also maybe your local database is different than your server.. just thinking

Comment: I removed the md5 part just to avoid confusion here and to test it in the server and stills happening the same.

Comment: Test your output by doing a log to your console for the password and see what the differences are.